# Why are my CIFAR-10 dict keys different than what they should be?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to load the CIFAR-10 dataset in python but the names of the keys that it displays are quite out of the norm. `dict.keys()` gives the folowing output:

`dict_keys([b'labels', b'batch_label', b'data', b'filenames'])`

What is the "b" outside the names of the keys?

I used the code given on the dataset's website for unpickling:

```
def unpickle(file):
import pickle
with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
    dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
return dict
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `b` in front of the beginning of the string means that the string is encoded in unicode (their type is byte). You can convert them back to `str` using the `decode` method. More about python and unicode  [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html).